# Uso da função sub no R - string com carácteres especiais

Tags: r

Estou operando uma base de dados com os seguintes valores:

dados$Col_Nova <- dados$Col_Velha

```
Col_Velha              Col_Nova
MÃ©dico                Médico
MÃ©dica Intensivista   Médico
TÃ©cnica em Enfermagem TÃ©cnica em Enfermagem
Enfermeira             Enfermeiro
```

Para realizar a troca dos nomes usei a função sub com os seguintes parâmetros

```
dados$Col_Nova <- sub(pattern = "[A-z]nfermeir[A-z].*", "Enfermeiro", dados3$Col_Nova)
dados$Col_Nova <- sub(pattern = "[A-z].{3}ic[A-z].*", "Médico", dados$Col_Nova)
```

Entretanto, quando estou tentando aplicar para técnico de enfermagem não está funcionando, como segue o código:

```
dados$Col_Nova<- sub(pattern = "[A-z].{2}cnic[A-z]\\s.*", "Técnico de enfermagem", dados$Col_Nova)
```

O que está acontecendo e por quê?
Obrigado!

Comment: No seu lugar, eu tentaria ajustar o encoding da leitura desses dados. A coluna velha pelo menos está consistente: parece um dado UTF-8 que está sendo tratado como windows-1252.

Comment: Como eu faria isso?

Comment: Como você carregou esses dados?

Comment: dados <- read.csv(arquivos[indice_arquivos], header=T), onde arquivos é um vetor com os arquivos do diretório e indice_arquivos o nome do arquivo que eu quero importar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você pode alterar o a codificação da coluna toda de uma vez

```
dados$Col_Nova <- iconv(dados$Col_Velha, to = "latin1//TRANSLIT", from = "UTF-8")
```

Comment: Solução mostrou-se eficiente e prática para o problema proposto. Atenciosamente, Arduin.

Answer (score 1):

você colocou as barras invertidas

```
dados$Col_Nova <- sub(pattern = "[A-z].{2}cnic[A-z]\\s.*", "Técnico de enfermagem", dados$Col_Nova)
```

Comment: Verdade, mas mesmo assim aparece esse erro: "Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, Col_Nova, value = character(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 186" Acho que o padrão não está correto.

Comment: aqui rodou sem problemas

Answer (score 1):

Outra alternativa, que considero mais elegante, é tratar o encoding do arquivo na carga do mesmo, ao invés de corrigir erros de carga mal configurada.

É possível definir o encoding na leitura de arquivo, da seguinte forma:

```
csvFile <- file("arquivo.csv", encoding="UTF-8")
data <- read.csv(csvFile)
```

Acompanhando o seu caso nos outros comentários, é possível que o ajuste seja assim:

```
dados <- read.csv(file(arquivos[indice_arquivos], encoding="UTF-8"), header=T)
```

Como você não postou o código completo, não é possível garantir. Mas se não for, vai ser próximo disso.